# Mirabile visu, horribile dictu ― is this the ablative?

Tags: ablative

Are the expressions "mirabile visu", and "horribile dictu", in the ablative case? If so, shouldn't it be "mirabili visu", and "horribili dictu"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never forget about meaning, without which an expression turns into a collection of separate words. Your question presumes that the two words form a noun-modifier phrase *mīrābilis vīsus* "a strange, fascinating sighting", *horribile* *dictum* "a horrible saying", put in the Ablative case. If this were the case, the ending would indeed be wrong in the Latin of the classical period, or generally of antiquity, where *-ī* is standard. That said, *-e* becomes quite common towards the medieval period following the collapse of the Accusative with the Ablative, and it can be occasionally seen in the medievally-tinged Latin of the Renaissance.

However, as soon as you recall that the actual meaning of these expressions is **"strange to see"** and **"hair-raising to say"**, you will realise that you aren't dealing with a single noun phrase in the Ablative, but with two separate phrases, a head and a complement: ***mīrābile** < mīrābilis* "strange" and ***vīsū** < vidēre/vīsus* "to see/to the sight".

- The first word is the head, formally a neuter adjective in the Accusative that can functionally be an adverb (the so-called 'adverbial Accusative'), e.g. *mīrābile sonāre* 'to sound pleasantly unusual'. This is also the case here - in fact the whole phrase is a parenthetical sentence disjunct, just like in "And then - *to my horror!* - I saw...". At first blush the adjective proper can be in any grammatical case that its function requires (e.g. Accusative in *mīrābilem vīsū effigiem* "a most remarkable, uncanny image/likeness"). However on practice it never seems to be used in the Ablative or the Dative precisely because this would result in a double-reading as a single noun phrase ([Garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence)). This is therefore very strictly avoided.
- The second word is a complement dependent upon the first and completing its meaning. This form is known as the **supine** (here's [a friendly article on these](https://latinitium.com/the-supine-in-latin-grammar/) by Latinitium), and the one we have here is doubly problematic:

  - Firstly, it can be said to be both nominal "to the sight" and verbal "to see". Evidently it moved from the former to the latter category in the course of time.
  - Secondly, its case superficially appears to be Ablative (and many a school grammar will tell you the same), but its meaning clearly points towards the Dative (which is the origin of the Infinitive in many other languages incl. English); moreover, the Latin found outside of school grammars actually had a Dative in *-ū* as an alternative and seemingly more original form, which makes the latter explanation by far preferrable.
  - See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/how-is-the-supine-related-to-the-derived-fourth-declension-noun) for more discussion on both these points.

Comment: I think that it could be relevant to clarify why you say that "the first word (...) functionally _can_ be an adverb" (italics mine). I think this point is not obvious if it is not exemplified.

Comment: @Mitomino Is the illustration and explanation I added sufficient? I mean, it's a general fact about Latin adjectives that they can be used adverbially at will.

Comment: Thanks to the illustration & explanation you provided, now I see your point. I do agree that _mirabile visu_ can function as a parenthetical "disjunct", which is, by the way, different from the adverbial "adjunct" _mirabile_ in _mirabile sonare_. Furthermore, it is clear that this expression (_mirabile visu_) can appear in other contexts: e.g. _id uero horrendum ac uisu mirabile ferri_ (Verg. _Aen._ VII, 78). When referring to the disjunct use, you say "this is also the case here". Here? Well, the OP does not provide any context where this expression is inserted.

Comment: @Mitomino Yes, I noticed it was different as a parenthetical disjunct and as a manner adjunct during my latest edit.—The phrase in question is almost universally adduced in the neuter, and not the m/f as is usual with adjectives intended to agree in gender, the reason evidently being that it's precisely the parenthetical use that is meant, seen as more common or interesting I suppose. I try to allow for its use as an adjective in other contexts by saying that the neuter form *can* be used as an adverb. Maybe I should also say "is often used as a disjunct".