# Verb + dative/ablative-supine

Tags: grammar-choice, supinum

According to [A&G](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/supine), the ablative supine with verbs is "extremely rare" and even the example given: *pudet dictu* is somewhat not regular since *pudet* is impersonal (as if it is almost an adjective).

(1) What are other classical examples of the usage of the u-supine with verbs?

(2) In [Gen 3:17](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Z1kAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22tibi%20esu%22&source=bl&ots=1tgrjdhvvN&sig=ACfU3U3LQo97m_IKFbpregRwS1bxMQO6pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmr5rR9MvwAhUoUhUIHWExC8YQ6AEwDHoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22tibi%20esu%22&f=false) of Sebastian Castellio:

> Deinde ad Adamum: quia uxori tuae morem, inquit, gerens, de arbore comedisti, **cuius ego tibi esu interdixeram**, erit humus infelix propter te, quaeresque ex ea victum laboriose per omnem vitam".

Can we justify this usage of the supine by Castellio attaching the u-supine with *interdixeram*? (**See** note at the bottom)

(3) Castellio maybe using double dative construction here (whether of not this use makes sense with *interdico*), but then should we expect *esui* (4th declation dative of esus)? or rather any 4th declination nouns based on verbs to be declined as ablative? for example should we use *esu* or *esui* here:

> hoc relinquo animalibus **esu/esui** (I leave it for animals to eat[as a food for animals])

---

**Edit:** With respect to (2), it now occurred to me, that *esu* is probably a regular ablative of the noun *esus*, as *interdico* can be joined with ablative of the thing prohibited. In our case (the eating of which..)

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** The answer to this question was already given [in another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4177/can-the-supine-ablative-be-used-for-motion), :as stated, there are examples but primarily not classical. Most teaching sources don't even mention this as a possibility, writing only that "The Supine in -u (Dative and Ablative) is used with some Adjectives ..." ([Kennedy, The revised Latin primer, p.167](https://archive.org/details/revisedlatinprim00kenniala/page/166/mode/2up)); A&G could not stress the rarity more with the "extremely rare". [A copious Latin Grammar p.255](https://books.google.com/books?id=4E8QAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=primus%20cubitu%20surgat&source=bl&ots=RTGSSVHo55&sig=ACfU3U01iKfkHnyVe2xqnM9w-bxL-MilSA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikt4PIsczwAhUP3KQKHc2MBr4Q6AEwE3oECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=primus%20cubitu%20surgat&f=false) notes that if the u-supine is joined with verbs those are **"verbs to the question from what"** and gives the following examples:

> obsonatu redeo (return from marketing) [Plaut. Men. 2.2.5]

> primus cubitu surgat (Let him rise from bed first) [Cat. R. R. 5]

**(3)** Given the answer in (1) it can be said with enough certainty that the use of *esu* in: "hoc relinquo animalibus *esu*" to designate a double dative construction is off. Though indeed the u-supine traces his origin in some respects back to the dative of purpose, we should not feel uneasy using the regular 4th declination dative suffix *-ui* in double dative construction . There are examples:

> communis autem usus serpentes fugare, **percussis esui** dari(*) decoctum.   (All kinds are used to keep away serpents, are given to eat boiled to those who have been bitten. Loeb translation). [N.H. 20.178]

Actually, As "Alex B" [mentions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4434/4796) ui-supines forms also exist, so again, there seem to be no reason to be deterred by the origin of the u-supine and to suggest it also includes the dative case in it.

(*) Loeb reads here *dare*